# Local storage in Protractor?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node

I am writing automation test cases for the first time.I am trying to write e2e testcases using Jasmine/Protractor in Angular.
So here I will give you a scenario. Like when I serve/build my project. The page which loads is **"Terms and Conditions"** and there are 2 buttons Accept and Decline.

> When i click Accept it will be creating a local storage
>   **"isAccepted"** with value **true**

Now my question here is

"How do I create a local storage or mimic the same kind of scenario using Protractor with Angular when I run the command **Protractor**?"

Our project is being built on Angular with Ionic framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a javascript snippet in browser via `browser.executeScript()` api.

```
var script = "window.localStorage.setItem('isAccepted', 'true')";
browser.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: That worked as expected.! Made it like this.
browser.get('/');
var script = "window.localStorage.setItem('isAccepted', 'true')";
return browser.executeScript(script);